# Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: .net, samsung-smart-tv

Can we create apps for Samsung Smart TV in dot net?

If no, which languages can we use to create them? I guess Adobe AIR is one.

Answer (score 21):

Download SAMSUNG TV APPS SDK and use the "Apps editor" and the "Visual Editor" included in the SDK to create programs.

In the Visual Editor you create scenes that can be used in the program. A Scene can contain components from the toolbar, like textboxes, listboxes and so on, following components are predefined:

- Button: Handles button events
- Check Box: Provides a check box button for selecting options
- Date Picker: Allows the user to select calendar dates
- Help Bar: Displays a 960px-width bar at the bottom of the screen.
- Image: Displays an image.
- Input: Provides an empty field into which the user can enter text
- Label: Displays a simple string
- List Box: A vertical list
- Loading Image: Displays a waiting image for situations like network loading
- Popup: Displays a popup message with an OK button
- Popup (OK, Cancel): Displays a popup message with an OK button and a Cancel button
- Scrollbar: Displays the currently selected position on a list
- Video: Provides movie playback/volume buttons

For each type of component, there is an XML file which defines its default properties and parameters. This includes the component's thumbnail image, default size, resize options, etc. When you drag a component from the Component panel to the editing window, an instance of the component is created according to the elements in the XML files. These properties can then be adjusted for the specific instance in the Visual Editor.

In the Apps Editor you import your scenes and bind it together with code to make an functional program. You are working with CSS and javascript. You can run the program in the emulator and trace errors using the Log Manager Panel.
[image]

All SmartTV applications are in fact html-applications running online from the server containing the apps. A small part (icons and some other information, sometimes media is downloaded to get fast access) are downloaded and installed on the TV but it seems like you can't run the program without internet connection on the TV so it seems like it needs to connect and run it from the source.

I have'nt succeeded in uploading a project to run on my smart-TV yet, so anyone that has done it, please enter more information here about that.

**Samsung TV Application SDK**
The Samsung TV Application SDK (SDK) can be downloaded from the Samsung Developer Forum in the SDK & Tools section under Apps Guide menu. It is currently compatible only with Windows OS. Please register at [www.samsungdforum.com/eu](http://www.samsungdforum.com/eu) to download it.

Comment: Does this Visual Editor still exist in the 2015 IDE? I can't find it, nor reference to it.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I went deep in Samsung docs you can do your apps in:

- `JavaScript`,
- `Adobe Flash`/`AIR`, but only for Flash Player v.9
- and haven't try but there is api for `LUA` language

Comment: Since 2012 models - there is no `LUA` support.

Comment: Do you have by chance any link/etc to a statement that LUA has actually been removed? I can't find any, just like I can't find any info that it is supported.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can develop app using .Net, You have to redirect 
location.href="Your server address", from the widget

But in Samsung SDK they have strongly condemn this approach. so before taking this approach get in contact with Samsung guys and seek there prior permission otherwise your app will be rejected by Samsung QA team

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether .NET is available to develop apps for Samsung Smart TV,

but you can check the official website for Samsung Smart TV apps developer.
http://www.samsungdforum.com

I think this might helpful to you.
(I quoted from Samsung D Forum)

****Develop****
Download the latest version of SDK to start developing your Samsung SmartTV applications
Developers can find Samsung provides various version of SDK Package on the Samsung D Forum.
Samsung provides various documents & sample tutorials for creating different apps by using Samsung platform APIs.
While developing app, if user wants to add the Application Push feature, user need to apply for the Auth key in advance. Samsung Application Push supports both notification message and control message for applications.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible in a specific way because when you build a javascript project there are only html, css, js files to code in. The problem is smart tv's embedded js files. In the project they are referenced like

```
    <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js'></script>
```

if you find this js files from the Samsungs ide folder you can reference them normally then write like other html javascript projects and change them back when you install them on tv.

but i suggest that use samsungs ide , writing javascript is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

The widget itself can be created with Samsung Apps SDK and is installed on the TV. However, once you install the widget, the widget can load content from the Web. 
Therefore everything that happens inside the widget can actually be a .Net web application, so that you can develop almost all of it in .Net

Answer (score 0):

.NET is runnning only on Windows OS, so, my anser is No, and I don't think that MONO was also ported to run on... TV's...

But if you want to create apps, you should look what API is Samsung offering and search for SDK...

Comment: Not "only on windows" since we have MONO as you just said yourself. And actually, samsung smart tvs are linux-based.

Comment: I was speaking about compilers, the CLR and JIT compilers of .NET run only in Microsoft's ecosystem. Mono Project built their own compilers to run msil on other platforms. But, if you say that Smart TV's are linux based, then the only problem will be the headache to set mono up.

Comment: Please merge your response into your answer. I'll be then able to remove downvote and comment(s).

Answer (score 0):

Native apps, no - as far as I know.
But indirectly, yes.
The Samsung Smart TV has a browser, which I believe is Chrome-based (just saw a brief mention of that, not sure if it's fact yet).
So, you could develop in .net, host on Azure, and the Samsung Smart TV can use it.
It's not something that would be sold through the app store - you'd need some kind of subscription service in your app if appropriate.
Also, as far as I know, the SSTv doesn't provide local options for database storage, so if you need that, you'll need an outside database server somewhere.

In my opinion, SSTv apps are best paired up with an outside web app/service, which could be on any platform. Native apps running 'on' the TV do need to be developed in their IDE, though, which doesn't support a .net environment.

I'm working on a new project based on C#/MVC/Azure/SQL Azure/jquerymobile - all new technologies for me to be working with, and a hill of a learning curve coming from my COBOL/VB roots.

Had mom and dad check it on their new Samsung SmartTV, in the web browser.
It mostly worked.
Cookies might be an issue.
And navigation via the remote may not be as intuitive as expected, but mom and dad are in their 70's, so their tech intuition may also not be quite as quick :-)

If you want it to work on the SSTv, a hybrid approach may be best if you want to do much of the development in the .net environment.

Greg

Comment: Not all units have a browser. My Smart-TV and my BlueRay-unit with SMart HUb has no browser available, and there are no browser-app to download for what I can see....

Comment: @Stefan Whole Smart Hub resides in browser (but let say in full-screen mode)

Comment: @Dobiatowski, that may be the truth, but its not like you can use that to publish a web app to the unit, its locked to the HUB. The unit has to have a browser app where you can surf on the net to use the tip above, and my two units doesnt have that, and I bought them last month (blue ray) and 6 months ago (tv).

Comment: @Stefan Yes, but as you create the app using HTML/JavaScript you can put an iframe to the index.html which can open the remote server webpage. Another thing is how to handle the navigation on it ;) but at last it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an application on Samsung Smart-TV and it's all done with web technologies (HTML, PHP, JavaScript, CSS...) 
You can work with eclipse too! Actually, Samsung will suggest downloading eclipse with its plugin in it.

Comment: Hi, Just need to ask you did samsung QA team passed your app, and were u able to launch it

Comment: Hi @abhi , I did not submit my app to Samsung. It was an internship project.

Comment: ok, because as per my knowledge and experience samsung don't allow server hosted app, and they reject these apps at qa process

Answer (score 0):

You can develop apps using languages like javascript and flash.. IN the latest sdks (2014) you can even develop native applications using cpp